# web selenium testing can't locate element

Tags: python, selenium

This code should open flickr website and search for "s" and click search photos from suggestions.

But I get the following error:

> "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),'Search photos')]"}
> (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.85)"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.flickr.com/")
#webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait(driver, 1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='search-field']").send_keys("s")
webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait(driver, 1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Search photos')]").click()
webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait(driver, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there an wrong initializing the **`WebDriverWait`**.

And to click *`Search photos`* try using `.execute_script(..)`method with `arguments[0].click();` argument.

Try the following code snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.flickr.com/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

search_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='search-field']")))
search_field.send_keys("s")
 
search_photos = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Search photos')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search_photos)
```

Comment: Thanks. i hade to replace last two lines with "search_photos = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-href='/search/?text=s']")))
search_photos.click()" and it worked now!

Comment: @EslamAshraf yes it will worked for this this case, but if you change the search key other than `s` it won't work.

Comment: yes, i'm aware of that but i think this's the only solution since chrome can't accept this other line

Comment: @frianH is right.  My original solution was not a good one, I didn't catch at the time that the data-ref value was dynamic depending on what you are searching for.  That is not a good solution. I tried replacing it with something more re-usable but it's not working consistently. I deleted my original reply.